# Symfony/Doctrine issue : Saving entities not in order

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I have a question about doctrine persistance mechanisme.

***Situation :***
I have a ManyToMany relation,and I add some entities in a **defined order**, but when I retrieve my entities there are retrieved in a different order.
it's like doctrine change the order when saving entities.

***Example :***
Obj_A (id=3) and
Obj_B1 (id = 2) , Obj_B2 (id = 5), Obj_B3 (id = 1)

when retrieved, the order of Obj_B* id 
obj3, obj1, obj2 it's like an id order.

Can you help me please. I have to retrieve theme in the initial order.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Resolved, Normally doctrine sort the entries by id (primary key) so, to save order with must create a class-association with it's own Id (that will keep the sort).